# Running a PHP application as part of a Jenkins build on CloudBees

Tags: cloudbees

I want to run some integration tests against my app on Jenkins/Cloudbees. Deploying on Quercus is not an option since some parts of the app (nusoap) do not work properly.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only command line PHP is available on build slaves, so you have to deploy your app on a php hosting service to run such integration tests.

Please note recent php version can [run a basic http server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), so you can start your web application